# Any way to cache the current user object in memory without going through the login/signup calls and localStorage?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

In Parse, a user object is created and cached in memory after login or signup successfull calls, and can be retrieved using current.

My need now is to create and cache the user object in memory without going through the login/signup calls and also without having to store the object in the local storage. I mean something like assigning a new user object in memory so that `Parse.User.current` will return it. Again I shouldn't go through login and signup.

If I go through login call:

```
Parse.User.logIn(login, password, {
      success: function(user) {
      // At this moment the user object is cached
      },
       error: function(error) {
      }
});
```

But in my case, I don't go through the login, but instead I have the user id, and with it I can get the user object:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo('objectId',result.id);
query.first({

        success: function(user){
                // Now I want to cache the user in memory so that Parse.User.current will return it to me whenever I want
                // I tried to cache this in localStorage but whenever I retrieve it, I get null object
        },  
        error: function(error){
                alert(error);
        }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're opening a massive security hole if you want to allow signing in as users without their passwords just based on the `objectId`. If the user is explicitly signing out, then they should sign back in so you have access to the current user again.

Comment: You right, I am not pleased with that but phonegap limitations are putting me in the corner again.

Comment: I have worked on this and just used the FacebbokUtils, but know I am running into a small issue, If you can help with me that would be appreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327316/parse-facebookutils-login-doesnt-connect-after-getting-authdata-from-a-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want, but you could simply call `toJSON()` on the current user and save that JSON in your cache, either local storage or whatever you are using.

Is there more you want? If so please expand your question.

Comment: Basically, I cannot go through the login process because I don't know the password, instead I know the id of the user, so I want to cache the user object in memory like it's done when login/signup calls are achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Parse users are logged in until they log out, parse caches the user for you.

You can access that cached user by doing this in your code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User.Current());
```

see docs:

https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-after-signing-up-logging-in-via-the-rest-api

Comment: Hi, please have a look at my edit. I have already tried localstorage and each time I retrieve the user object, I got null

Comment: Hi, please provide suggestions in javascript as some features are implemented in iOS SDK but not in JS SDK.

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-to-keep-a-user-logged-in-after-signing-up-logging-in-via-the-rest-api

Comment: That link is the javascript solution let me know if that helps. Sorry about IOS.

Comment: var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User.Current())

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. keeping the user session is a way to keep the user logged in. But in my case there will be signing out through Parse. So I cannot rely on the session token etc. My ultimate needs are to assign somehow the value which I am getting through `Parse.User.current`

Comment: If they sign out via pass, the session is closed on the server, the local api will thus not be usable.